# Is it possible to run asp on linux with Apache?

Tags: apache, asp-classic

The production environment is now LAMP,

I don't know whether it's possible to serve **asp** requests on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running ASP.Net on a Linux based server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116175/running-asp-net-on-a-linux-based-server)

Comment: Not a duplicate. ASP.Net is a different animal

Answer (score 6):

Same as a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/747375/25163): The answer is a big "it depends".

**Are you talking about Classic ASP?**
Sun has (had?) a product out called "SunOne ASP" - though the product changed names so many times I couldn't say what it really is other than the original ChiliSoft ASP product bought and re-named by Sun.

Anyway, the aforementioned product would allow you to run ClassicASP/VBScript code on a *nix server, and for the most part would run it well. It was a little fussier about certain things, and there were certain things that didn't work quite right, but if you were hell-bent on doing it you could make it work. Having said all that, I think I read somewhere that the project was discontinued. So it may not be available anymore.

There's also an Apache:ASP module that (in my experience) only works with code written with it in mind. If you're trying to port an application from a Windows server, its one of those "split your risk" options.

**Are you talking about ASP.NET?**
If this is the case, you've got a better chance... the aforementioned [Mono Project](http://mono-project.com/) would be your best bet. Its come a long way since I last looked at it, but having not had to set anything up with it I really can't speak to how good/bad it is.

**All things being equal...**
All things being equal, I would really say that if you're going to use an MS programming language, run it on an MS server. It may cost a little extra, but it will probably save you more headaches in the long run.

Comment: `Apache::ASP` uses PerlScript, and does not support VBScript, the de-facto language of "Classic ASP" pages, so it's not really an option for running such websites.

Comment: @MestreLion all they asked was asp-classic. No language was specified, ergo the answer given. And Oracle has continued the old Sun product that did offer limited VBScript support.

Comment: True, and you're not alone: there are dozens of answers in similar questions recommending `APACHE::ASP`, and basically none mentions this "little" caveat. But let's be honest: since most (if not all) websites that used ASP were written in VBScript, any webserver that does not support is not a true solution.

Comment: @MestreLion I've worked on enough JScript sites, and even a few Python/ASP sites, to not assume VBScript unless stated. Either way, we also have the latter half of my comment - and the product that took up the first half of my answer.

Comment: @AnonJr when someone asks for classic asp asks for VBscript/COM objects. This is the 'classic' question from a Windows web developer that runs ASP and wants to port to UNIX. The answer is no. Use PHP instead the facto standard for script web language in *nix system. Apache::ASP was a joke from the GNU community to make a total different language since ASP is a copyright from Microsoft and you need ActiveX objects to do anything usable like access to a database.

Comment: @Juanjo I've worked with several people who successfully deployed ASP/VBScript sites on Sun One (ne ChilliSoft) on Unix servers, so the answer to the actual question is "Yes, it is possible". Also, as previously noted, no lang was stated and I've seen enough ASP/JScript and ASP/Python sites to not assume unless otherwise stated (ditto with the assumption it was Classic ASP - which was not clear in '12 when the answer was given). Regardless, please answer the person's question with your own answer (not as a comment on mine); or, comment on the full answer given and previous comment replies.

Answer (score 4):

It is.

- [Classic ASP](http://www.apache-asp.org/)
- [ASP.NET](http://www.mono-project.com/ASP.NET)

Whether or not a specific ASP program will run is a different story.

Comment: ASP and ASP.NET are almost completely different and "Classic ASP" seems to be a Perl module that allows you to use Perl in scripts. Neither seems to run ASP/VBScript

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes - but YMMV on how well it supports your code.

Check out:  http://www.apache-asp.org/

And also google for mod_aspnet, if you're using .Net.

Gotta say, it's pretty bad on your management to move your production environment to LAMP without checkking that your Code supports it!

Comment: [sarcasm]Managers exist for the sole purpose of making developers' lives difficult[/sarcasm]