# Is it possible to use ASP in a Apache server?

Tags: apache, asp-classic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run asp on linux with Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848975/is-it-possible-to-run-asp-on-linux-with-apache)

I am developing an application were I need to use ASP to do a transformation process in the server side using XSLT style sheets. I am using a Apache server. Is it possible to use ASP in a Apache server? Is there something you need to install or configure?

Comment: Only with PerlScript, no VBScript as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be something called ChilisoftASP but not sure of the current state of that software. Perhaps install something like Mono, I believe asp.net has support for classic asp.