# Express - retrieving .asp files using res.sendFile downloads the file rather than displaying it in the browser. Is there a solution?

Tags: node.js, express, asp-classic

Title.

I'm wondering if it's even possible to host `.asp` files on a Node Express server, given that they're proprietary. I've looked into a solution to this problem to no avail, so I was wondering if or how it can be done.

The purpose of this is for migrating a site previously hosted on Windows IIS to my new Express server. I'm unsure as to the details of `.asp` and was just looking for some help shedding light on the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ASP-Classic script files (.asp) need to be interpreted on the server. If your server does not know how to run them (like IIS does) there's no way this can work.

Comment: @Filburt That's what I feared...nothing I can do about asp on a linux based server then?

Comment: [Is it possible to run asp on linux with Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848975/is-it-possible-to-run-asp-on-linux-with-apache) looks promising ... if Apache is an option for you.